# Least squares regression with sample weights on statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels, survey

I am looking to implement OLS with sample weights on statsmodels. The specific application is the American Time Use Survey, in which sample weights adjust for demographic balances with respect to the population. If there is no direct implementation, then  assistance in hard coding the estimator with sample weights would also be helpful.

Comment: It seems that the freq_weights in the GLM model can fufill your needs, pls refer to https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mario, you could try [WLS](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html) from statsmodels

An example from documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

Y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4]
X = range(1,8)
X = sm.add_constant(X)
wls_model = sm.WLS(Y,X, weights=list(range(1,8)))
results = wls_model.fit()

print (results.params)
```

More examples [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/wls.html).

Comment: Thank you. Estimation is via weighted least squares. I merely got confused because WLS is typically motivated from the point of view of improving efficiency rather than mitigating response bias, which is what the sample weights are for.